# iOS NSGenericException occurs randomly, not after a specific Action or event

Tags: ios, random, uinavigationcontroller, segue

my application crashes at random moment, i get the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'endOfGame'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

I have only push segues and i have add a navigation controller to my initial view

Does anybody have any idea whats causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Check the segue: `endOfGame`. To get more information try: Add an exception breakpoint. Go to the "Breakpoint Navigator", click on the "+" at the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint." Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint click debug continue a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post thatand an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages.

Comment: @zaph thank you zaph .Now i know why i got this exception.Sometimes [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"endOfGame" sender:self] was called when i was in another view controller because of a timer.